# Angular How to unit test error function in subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit test for subscribe call but I am not able to cover the error handling part of the subscribe method. In case of 403 error there is a handleError funtion which handles error for statusCode=403 and other statusCodes. Any help will be highly appreciated!

component.ts file

```
  getData(){
    this.someService.getResponse().subscribe(res=>{

    this.showForm=true;
    this.Form.patchValue({
      flag:res && res.someflag? "true" : "false"
    })
  },((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {       
      this.handleError(error);
    })); 
  }
```

handleError() function in component.ts file

```
  handleError(error){
    this.showForm=false;
    if(error.error && error.error.statusCode === 403){
       this.itemError=false;
       this.overlayError=true;
    }
    else{
      this.itemError=true;
      this.overlayError=false;
    }
  }
```

component.spec.ts file

This is what I tried but it is not covering the test case.

```
it('should handle error for 403',async()=>{
  const param={statusCode:403};
  const errorResponse=new Error('403 errror');
  spyOn(component["someService"],"getResponse").and.returnValue(throwError(errorResponse));

  component.handleStatusCodeError(param);
  expect(component.showForm).toBe(false);   
  expect(component.itemError).toBe(false);  
  expect(component.overlayError).toBe(true);  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
const errorResponse = new Error('403 error');
```

you should mock the response as following

```
const errorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({ status: 403, error: {}});
```

Comment: @C the one Thanks it worked! :) now my function is getting covered in the code coverage but this line (  this.handleError(error);  ) in component.ts is not getting covered.

Comment: you should fire it : component.handleError(error) etc @blume0F